# Parallel calls to CouchDB

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I'd like to stress test a CloudDB cluster with Python3 but I can't get the multithreading to work properly. I have used Google and there are MANY ways to do this, most of them are way to complicated for me and/or this use case.

What I try to do is save a document to CouchDB on 3 nodes at the same time. 
How would I use the most simple way of multithreading possible for this?

```
import couchdb
import random
import time
import _thread

servers = {
    "pizerogrijs": "http://admin:admin@pizerogrijs.local:5984/",
    "pizerogeel": "http://admin:admin@pizerogeel.local:5984/",
    "pizeroroze": "http://admin:admin@pizeroroze.local:5984/"
}

databasename = 'testhijs'

class bank(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dbs = {}
        for s in servers:
                self.dbs[s] = couchdb.Server(servers[s])[databasename]

    def showdbs(self):
        print(self.dbs)

    def randomwrite(self, data):
        randomdb = self.dbs[random.choice(list(self.dbs))]
        return(randomdb.save(data))

    def directwrite(self, server, data):
        start = time.time()
        directdb = self.dbs[server]
        end = time.time()
        print(directdb.save(data))
        print(end - start)

def streskip(server):
    db.directwrite(server, {"Test": "Thijs"})

db = bank()

_thread.start_new_thread(streskip('pizerogrijs'), ())
_thread.start_new_thread(streskip('pizerogeel'), ())
_thread.start_new_thread(streskip('pizeroroze'), ())

while 1:
   pass
```

The response is:

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/thijs/Repos/DataBos/test.py
('f4e66074fdae56c6de6b1d744033eb63', '1-a8238505469902134486a6744284a43a')
9.5367431640625e-07
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thijs/Repos/DataBos/test.py", line 39, in <module>
    _thread.start_new_thread(streskip('pizerogrijs'), ())
TypeError: first arg must be callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: "I'd like to use the most simple way of multithreading possible."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add arguments in a tuple and not directly. Like so.

```
_thread.start_new_thread(streskip, ('pizerogrijs',))
_thread.start_new_thread(streskip, ('pizerogeel',))
_thread.start_new_thread(streskip, ('pizeroroze',))
```

The rest of the code is fine and the most simple way of multi threading I could find.